# ¿Cómo hago para obtener los valores de una fila cuando le de click en visual basic o js?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Lo que pasa es que tengo un `ASPxGridView` y quiero que cuando le de <kbd>click</kbd> a una fila pueda obtener y guardar los valores de cada columna en una variable ya sea en `visual basic` o `js`.

¿Cómo hago para obtener los valores de una fila cuando le de <kbd>click</kbd> en `visual basic` o `js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás esto te pueda ayudar!!

```
Protected Sub Grilla_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles Grilla.RowDeleting
                Try
                    Dim fila As GridViewRow = Grilla.Rows(e.RowIndex)
                    Dim aux As String = CType(fila.FindControl("nombre_label"), Label).Text
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End Sub
```